# Datagridview in C# is not retrieving all the records from SQL server database

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a visual studio project for our student records and the records are coming from our online registration app. Then the database saves it. But the problem is my datagridview is not retrieving all the records from the database when I'm trying to retrive it using my other app. In other words our online app gathers data online and the other app is used to displays it for processing.

```cs
private void DisplayOnlineApplications(List<StudentInformationOnlineModel> Applicants)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

    foreach (var applicant in Applicants)
    {
        string gender = applicant.Gender.Substring(0, 1);
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(applicant.ApplicationID, applicant.StudentStatus, applicant.LRN, applicant.StudentName, gender, applicant.EmailAddress, applicant.MobileNo, applicant.EducationLevel, applicant.CourseStrand, applicant.YearLevel, applicant.ApplicationDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm tt"));
        dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Tag = applicant;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the query you are using to retrieve `List<StudentInformationOnlineModel> Applicants`.

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something, but is there some reason the code adds the rows to the grid “manually”? Is there some reason you do not simply use `Applicants` as a `DataSource` to the grid?

Comment: Have you verified that the `Applicants` list actually has any records, for instance what is the value of `dataGridView1.Rows.Count` after the loop? There are other known issues when you are using databindings, but because you are directly populating the _Rows_ property this is expected to simply _work_.  If the count is greater than 0, then check that you don't have other code that it altering the rows collection. (We assume you have already verified that this method is called at all)

Comment: oh i got the answer now. thank you all very much for all your assistance

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs some improvements. You don't need to manually add rows. Simply do.

```
private void DisplayOnlineApplications(List<StudentInformationOnlineModel> Applicants)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = Applicants;
}
```

For `Gender` field you can handle `DataGridView.CellFormatting` event

```
private void DataGridView1_CellFormatting(
    object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    var dataPropertyName = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName;
    if (dataPropertyName == nameof(StudentInformationOnlineModel.Gender))
    {
        e.Value = (e.Value as string).Substring(0, 1);
    }
}
```

If you need to get your object in row then you can do (at index `0` for example)

```
var item = dataGridView1.Rows[0].DataBoundItem;
var studentInformationOnlineModel = item as StudentInformationOnlineModel;
```